# AutoDataAttribute's concrete object creation logic calls all property getters once

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

Using AutoFixture 3.50 and xUnit.NET, it seems that there is a difference between the way that `Fixture.Create()` creates concrete objects and the way that AutoData Theory tests create concrete objects.

**Simple example:**

```
public class Foo
{
    private string prop;
    public string Prop
    {
        get
        {
             if (prop == null) { prop = "Prop"; } // Breakpoint 'A'
             return prop;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test using `Fixture`:**

```
[Fact]
public void FixtureTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var result = fixture.Create<Foo>(); // Breakpoint 'B1'
}
```

**Test using `AutoDataAttribute`:**

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void AutoDataTest(Foo sut)
{
    var bar = 1; // Essential no-op, Breakpoint 'B2'
}
```

In the former test, breakpoint 'B1' is hit while Breakpoint 'A' is never hit. In the latter test, breakpoint 'A' is hit before breakpoint 'B2' is hit. This is problematic when I have "lazily" initialized property not dissimilar from the one above - because the backing field of the property is initialized before the test is run, I cannot test the initialization logic.

Is there a way to customize `AutoDataAttribute` so that I can get around this behavior? Or possibly, maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, in fact, not an AutoFixture issue, but rather an xUnit.net issue, if you will. You can reproduce it entirely without AutoFixture like this:

```
[Theory, ClassData(typeof(FooTestCases))]
public void ClassDataTest(Foo sut)
{
    var bar = 1; // Essential no-op, Breakpoint 'B3'
}

private class FooTestCases : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new Foo() };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If you debug into this `ClassDataTest`, you'll also hit breakpoint 'A' before you hit breakpoint 'B3'.

The reason is that the xUnit.net test runner wants to give you a good display name for each parametrised test, so it tries to create a readable string representation of all the arguments passed to each test case in a `[Theory]`.

When a data object doesn't explicitly override `ToString`, xUnit.net falls back to reading all the properties and build up a display string from those. That's what's happening here.

I've tried searching for some official documentation of that behaviour, but the best I've been able to find is [this](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/649). As suggested there, you can get around the issue by overriding `ToString`:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string prop;
    public string Prop
    {
        get
        {
            if (prop == null) { prop = "Prop"; } // Breakpoint 'A'
            return prop;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

This change stops breakpoint 'A' from being hit, both when using `ClassData` and `AutoData`. Whether or not you want to override `ToString` is another question.

If you don't want to override `ToString` on `Foo`, perhaps you can get around the issue by testing a test-specific child class that does override `ToString`, like this:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void AutoDataTestFoo(TestFoo sut)
{
    var bar = 1; // Essential no-op, Breakpoint 'B4'
}

public class TestFoo : Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

This also stops breakpoint 'A' from being hit.

As long as `Foo` isn't `sealed`, you should be able to do this. If `Foo` is `sealed`, I can't think of any other workaround than to write the test in the style of `FixtureTest`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!